# Is valgrind right? Is the memory lost?

Tags: c, valgrind

```
typedef struct Model
{
    int recordId;
    char *name;
}Model;

typedef struct ModelArray
{
    //keeps the size that the array was initially create with. When more elements are needed
    //we use this to add that many more elements
    int originalSize;
    //total number of elements that can be used
    int elements;
    //total number of elements used
    int count;
    //the actual array is stored here
    Model *source;
}ModelArray;

void initModelArray(ModelArray *array, int numberOfElements)
{
    array->originalSize = numberOfElements;
    array->elements = numberOfElements;
    array->count = 0;
    array->source = malloc(sizeof(Model)*numberOfElements);//0 bytes in 3 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 65
}

void deallocModelArray(ModelArray *array)
{
    if(array == NULL)
        return;

    array->elements = 0;
    array->count = 0;
    free(array->source);
    array->source = NULL;
    free(array);
}

main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ModelArray *models = malloc(sizeof(ModelArray));
    initModelArray(models, 10);
    deallocModelArray(models);
}
```

What is lost? Code looks fine to me. I'm  sure I could say array->source = NULL first but it's not needed, right?

Comment: "//for shortness I left out dealloc code" -- then we can't see what you did or didn't deallocate.

Comment: The deallocation code is pretty important here. Also, without seeing valgrind's message it's impossible to know what's leaking. My bet would be on 'source' not being deallocated before 'models' is freed, but I'm just guessing here. I shouldn't be.

Comment: You ask about memory leaks and "for shortness" you leave the dealloc code? It would be helpful if you included the code even though the question length might suffer.

Comment: Please provide the 'dealloc code'. As written the program trivially leaks memory. If there is a memory leak it is likely due to an error in the deallocation logic, which you don't provide.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.  I've fixed incorrect struct uses, compiled and valgrind is not reporting leaks.  Please paste a self-contained example.

Comment: you should use `struct ModelArray` or `Model` not `ModelArray` (without the strcut keyword)

Comment: it gives me the error (commment on line 19). I have confirmed that I am making the array and deallocating the array right, Thanks all.

Comment: I think you meant to write 'struct ModelArray { ... } ModelArray', not 'struct ModelArray { ... } Model'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To deallocate these structures correctly, you need to do the following, in this order:

```
free(models->source);
free(models);
```

If you do anything else, you're leaking memory.

Edit:

OK, having seen the Model struct, you're probably leaking the names, or at least valgrind thinks you do because you deallocate the ModelArray structure, which contains a pointer to a Model structure, which contains a char* which you don't free first.

So:

```
int i;
for( i=0; i<models->originalSize; i++ ) {
    if( models->source[i]->name != NULL ) {
        free( models->source[i]->name );
    }
}
free(models->source);
free(models);
```

And it would be a good idea to use calloc() instead of malloc() when allocating models->source in the first place. This will set all the name pointers to 0. Without this, the test for models->source[i]->name being non-NULL above might fail if name happens to contain some garbage (since using uninitialized memory produces undefined behavior.)

Comment: I bet he has free(moedls) but not free(models->source)

Answer (score 2):

Er... Yes, the memory is lost. Of course, it is lost, since you "left out dealloc code"!

How could you possibly expect anyone to answer your question when you "left out dealloc code"? The very essence of your question is whether your dealloc code is correct or not. And you decided to leave it out?

On top of that, there quite a few thing that make little sense in your code. What is

```
typedef struct ModelArray {
  ...
  Model *source; 
  ...
} Model;
```

supposed to mean? Why are you typedefing `struct ModelArray` as `Model`? In fact, your code will not even compile, since `Model *` is used inside the struct, where it is not declared yet. You also use `ModelArray` type in your code, while in reality there's no such type. You have `struct ModelArray`, but not just `ModelArray`. The code you posted is not real code. Post real code, please. (Apparently it was supposed to be `typedef struct ModelArray { ... } ModelArray;` with `Model` defined elsewhere.)

Finally, as an unrelated note, `//` comments is a C99 feature. In C99 the function return type cannot be omitted (no "implicit int" rule in C99), meaning that you have to declare your `main` function as `int main`.

Comment: this is not really an answer, just a repeat of existing comments.

Comment: Whether this repeats the comments or not, this *is* a answer. And the answer is "yes".

Comment: @AndreyT: before your edit (which I haven't seen when posted my comment) it doens't answer the "What is lost?" part. And about the Model var inside the Model struct I don't agree, linked list are done this way

Comment: BlackBear: Incorrect. Linked list is not "done this way". The code will not even compile, as I said above. Pay attention to the code, please. In C language when you are referring to the type that is being declared, you are forced to use the full name `struct TYPE`. You cannot use a typedef name that has not been declared yet.

Comment: I left out the Model struct being lazy, I felt it was a minor detail. I didn't think it would throw people off. Sorry. Lesson learned. It's in there now

Comment: @joels: You still have `typedef struct ModelArray { ... } Model;`, when your intent apparently was `typedef struct ModelArray { ... } ModelArray;`.